# Pull specific data from urllib

Tags: python, urllib

Hi Im looking to pull specific text from the website using this method, eg. songtitle etc.

```
 import urllib.request, json  with
 urllib.request.urlopen("https://radio.habboland.net/api/nowplaying/habboland")
 as url:
     data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
     print(data)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow! Could you include the output of the `print` statement and describe in more detail what problem you are running into?

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request, json
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
url = "https://radio.habboland.net/api/nowplaying/habboland"
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,}
request=urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers)
with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as req:
    data = json.loads(req.read().decode())
    print(data['now_playing']['song']['title'])
```

output:

```
Easter Prom Live
```